# Using unstack in R

Tags: r, dataset

I have a data frame that I wish to transpose from long to wide form. My advisor suggested using unstack and even wrote a bit of sample code to help me out. I'm able to run his sample code just fine (with placeholder variables) but I am having trouble actually applying it to my data. Here is my "sample code: "

```
Data1 <- data.frame(
DWNSTID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
Load = c(3, NA, 10, NA, NA),
X1 = c(10,14, 20, 40, 10),
X2=c(3,5,1,2,3),
Z1 = c(0.2, 0.7, 0.4, 0.3,0.2)
)
oo <- order(Data1$DWNSTID)
Data1 <- Data1[oo,]
Y <- Data1$Load[!is.na(Data1$Load)]
id <- as.numeric(ordered(Data1$DWNSTID))
idtbl <- table(id)
ns <- max(idtbl)
nr <- max(id)
my.unstack <- function(X, ID, nc=ns, x.names){
temp <- tapply(Data1$X1, Data1$DWNSTID, FUN=function(x, ns=nc){
tt <- as.vector(x)
if (length(tt) < ns)
tt <- c(tt, rep(0, ns-length(tt)))
return(tt)})
temp <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(temp), nrow=nr, ncol=ns, byrow=T))
names(temp) <- x.names
return(temp)
}
X1.names <- paste("X1", 1:ns, sep="_")
X2.names <- paste("X2", 1:ns, sep="_")
Z1.names <- paste("Z1", 1:ns, sep="_")
X1 <- my.unstack(Data1$X1, Data1$DWNSTID, nc=ns, X1.names)
X2 <- my.unstack(Data1$X2, Data1$DWNSTID, nc=ns, X2.names)
Z1 <- my.unstack(Data1$Z1, Data1$DWNSTID, nc=ns, Z1.names)
Data1_reshaped <- cbind (Y, X1,X2, Z1)
```

And here is the code with my variables of interest plugged in (I've omitted the parts that I didn't need to change/ran fine since I didn't want to clutter up the post any more than I already have):

```
X1 <- Data1$AG[!is.na(Data1$AG)]
X2 <- Data1$NONAG[!is.na(Data1$NONAG)]
Z1 <- Data1$HSG[!is.na(Data1$HSG)]

X1.names <- paste("X1", 1:ns, sep="_")
X2.names <- paste("X2", 1:ns, sep="_")
Z1.names <- paste("Z1", 1:ns, sep="_")
X1 <- my.unstack(Data1$X1, Data1$DWNSTID, nc=ns, X1.names)
X2 <- my.unstack(Data1$X2, Data1$DWNSTID, nc=ns, X2.names)
Z1 <- my.unstack(Data1$Z1, Data1$DWNSTID, nc=ns, Z1.names)
Data1_reshaped <- cbind (Y, X1,X2, Z1)
```

Can anyone clue me in to why the last 4 lines will not run? I am getting the message that vectors are of different lengths but am not sure how to take care of that problem. Specifically, X1, X2, and Z1 are all one length, but X1.names, X2.names, and Z1.names are all a different length. Isn't this problem inherent when reshaping data? I'm definitely not expecting someone to solve this problem for me, but I would appreciate advice on what I can try at this point.

My goal is for each row in the data frame to correspond to a LOAD value, while the columns will be AG1, AG2, AG3, and so on.

Comment: It would seem that `plyr` and `reshape` and related packages would be the better way to go about manipulating your data into alternative formats.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you there because it takes care of the different dimension issue. Just repeat for each var of interest and merge together.

```
library(data.table)
Data1 <- data.frame(
DWNSTID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
Load = c(3, NA, 10, NA, NA),
X1 = c(10,14, 20, 40, 10),
X2=c(3,5,1,2,3),
Z1 = c(0.2, 0.7, 0.4, 0.3,0.2)
)

Data1.dt <- data.table(Data1)
Data1.dt[,"group.id" := seq_len(.N), by=DWNSTID]

datax1 <- Data1.dt[,c("DWNSTID", "X1", "group.id"),with=FALSE]
X1 <- reshape(datax1, timevar = "group.id",  idvar = 'DWNSTID', direction = "wide")
```

Comment: Hi Tchotchke! Thank you so much for your answer. This seems like a smart way to handle the issue. But I'm having trouble understanding what line 11 of code is supposed to do. `datax1 <- Data1.dt[,c("DWNSTID", "X1", "group.id"),with=FALSE]` I'm so new to R. I apologize for even asking. If there's a better place on the internet I can go for help at this basic level please let me know. I appreciate your time!

Comment: That is one of the ways in data table to select the columns of interest. If you search for "data table r" you'll find a couple of good PDFs that go over the basics.

And welcome to SO. If you find the response helpful, please consider upvoting the answer and marking it as correct if it solved your question.